# Background color of a textView and seekBar value in android

Tags: android, colors, textview

I'm working on this project in which I use a seekBar to change color of a figure. That figure is represented by a textView with a specific background color set in xml. And while i change the value of the seekBar the color should vary.

let's say textView has color #xxxxxx. I want to get the value of this color and modify it  propotionaly with the value of the seekBar.

For example , if :

Case 1 : seekBar value increases 0 - > max => #yyyyyy (a different color for each value of the seekBar)

Case 2 : seekBar value decreases max-> 0 => #xxxxxx (same as above)

I know how to get the color of a textView :

```
ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) textView.getBackground();
int colorCode = cd.getColor();`
```

and also how to make the logic of the "increasing" and "decreasing" values of seekBar value.

I just can't figure it out how to use "progress" and color code together to go from x to y and from y to x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every color is composed by red green blue
so try this:

```
public int getColor(int progress) {
    int startColor = Color.parseColor("#xxxxxx");
    int endColor = Color.parseColor("#yyyyyy");

    int start_red = Color.red(startColor);
    int start_green = Color.green(startColor);
    int start_blue = Color.blue(startColor);
    int end_red = Color.red(endColor);
    int end_green = Color.green(endColor);
    int end_blue = Color.blue(endColor);

    int progress_red = start_red + (end_red - start_red) * progress / 100;
    int progress_green = start_green + (end_green - start_green) * progress / 100;
    int progress_blue = start_blue + (end_blue - start_blue) * progress / 100;

    int progress_color = Color.rgb(progress_red, progress_green, progress_blue);
    return progress_color;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising :D but one thing , i don't know exactly the yyyyyy value , but  I don't think that i will keep this condition standing and i will assign a finishing color and that's it. Thank for help :)

Comment: oh,  and btw , what should be maxValue for seekBar ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write method

```
int toColor(int progress)
```

which converts progress value from method onProgressChanged() of seekbar to int color, which you than set to background of textview:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(convertedColor);
```

Comment: and the max value of seekBar i presume it should be 255 ? and still i don't see any relation between old bg color and the new one .
Something like 
newBgColor = progress + oldBgColor

Comment: better use getMax() method of seekbar, because it could be overriden when creating seekbar